# Changing PivotTable Grand Total from Row to Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Quick question regarding the Excel PivotTable Grand Total. The feature is working great, nonetheless, I wanted to know if it is possible to change the format of the Grand total function from a row appearing at the bottom of the cells being used for the calculation to a column appearing to the right. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I apologize I am pretty new to Excel and need a bit of help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Can you edit your post and perhaps add a screenshot? Are you talking about a pivot table or something else?

Comment: Yes. I am talking about a pívot table, I apologize for not adding that in my question. All I want to know, is if it is possible to have the Grand Total appear on the right hand side as a column instead of at the bottom as a row, of course talking the sun of specific cells.

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy ways to do this.

1. Right-click context menu

Right click the pivot table and choose Pivot Table Options:
[image]

Click Totals & Filters then check/uncheck the row and/or column grand total:

[image]

2. Ribbon

Put your cursor in the pivot table then go to the Pivot Table Design and select an option from the Grand Totals menu:

[image]